# Issues in displaying search icon

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-search

I am trying to display a search icon on the custom toolbar!

Problem :
I had set the title of the toolbar to "Clubs List" while designing the toolbar, Now when I create a new menu.xml file to display the search icon on the toolbar, though the search icon is displayed on the right end side of toolbar but with the toolbar title("clubs list") even my app name in black color gets displayed on the left side as shown in the fig below("cric..")

I want only "CLUBS LIST" and search icon on the toolbar, How do I achieve this?

Here's my Toolbar.xml file
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/toolbarC"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/MyStyle"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
    android:text="CLUBS LIST"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here's my main xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:layout="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#3dcc24">

 <include
    layout="@layout/clubs_tool_bar" />

 <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my menu xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">>

 <item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:theme = "@style/MyStyle" />
  </menu>
```

Here's my Java file

```
public class Clubs_List extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbarC;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cricket_clubs);
    toolbarC = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarC);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarC);
 }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu,menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Here's my styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" 
    parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="MyStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name = "android:textSize">30sp</item>



   </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: In my opinion, you should not use textview for showing activity title. Because all titles in your app should be the same format. Remove textview and use standart title. You can set title text in code by setTitle(). You can configure title text style in styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May i know what theme have you applied to your activity in your manifest?

you might be giving wrong theme to your Activity to hide title.

```
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
```

In your Manifest give `MyTheme` to your Activity.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

in your activity

```
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: @style/AppTheme

Comment: @HoneyKhandelwal see the edited answer. hope it helps

Comment: I added the following code to style.xml and then changed the app theme of the toolbar to "Mytheme" but still, it doesn't work ! I still get the same screen as before

Comment: Try changing theme of Activity in manifest. See edited answer

Comment: Initially there was no app theme for my activity in manifest, I added the current theme into my activity in the manifest file but still the toolbar remains same as before

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` write this line of code in your activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155599/discussion-between-honey-khandelwal-and-n-moudgil).